# How can I render an object in a different material, each one in a separate image?

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I need to automate the rendering in order to show the variety of materials, of each component of my object. So I could use them to create a customization file.

I used a Compositing Nodetree to render and save each component, separately, as images in their specific folder. But I'm struggling to find a way to add to the "process", the variety of materials of each component.

I have over 20 components and each comes with at least 30 different materials…
So you can imagine how long it would take to do it manually ☹...
I had the idea to keyframe each material for all the component, and use the render animation, image sequences... but I don't know how????

so can you please help me automate it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the materials by their index with Set Material Index geometry node and you can animate its property. Just add all of the wanted materials to your component as a material slot, don't assign anything. With this method you can use only one material for each mesh, so if you have meshes with multiple material slots, you have to separate them first.

[image]

Comment: Hi @FFeller,
Thank you for your precious help, it works perfectly.
Please allow me one more question,
I can't find a way to assign an output name to rendered images? Is there a way to avoid renaming the exported images one by one?  is the solution in the Compositing File Output? thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help in that, I'm not experienced in scripting.  May be there is a python script or addon for this.

Comment: Thanks again @FFeller,